# What could I do to rescue some files from my sm-t320?

Tags: twrp, windows, mtp

I installed cyanogenmod and twrp v2.8.7.0 a very long time ago.
Now that the O.S. has broken I'd like to copy some files to pc (windows 10), but I failed to find any solution til now on forums/youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the version of TWRP on your device allows in the Mount section to Enable/Disable MTP, you can use it to connect to your PC and copy files from the internal storage to the PC.

Or you can insert an SD card, and copy files from the internal storage to the SD card using TWRP's terminal with the following command

```
cp -R /path/to/internal_storage /path/to/sdcard/folder
```

Then insert the SD card to PC and copy the files.

Comment: or install `twrp-3.3.1-0-mondrianwifi.img` when MTP does not work